# DigitalOcean ubuntu droplet error when using `su`

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean

I am using jenkins in order to build my projects on my digitalocean droplet. I recently got an error when i was trying to use `ssh` to check on my droplet. i am unable to use `su` command to change user on my droplet,

this is the output i get,
[image: <code>su jenkins</code> reroutes to root and anything i type is hidden]

`su jenkins` reroutes to root and anything i type is hidden. and when i run `whoami` i get `root` as the response. Is there any solution for this. i already tried restarting the droplet, but i am getting the same problem.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my problem fixed, this was happening because the `jenkins` user was using too much CPU resources. the `top` cmd showed that `jenkins` user was using `366%` CPU usage.

I removed all previous builds and updated jenkins to latest version and the restarted the droplet, this fixed this error for me.

Hope this would help some one else if faced with the same problem.